# I want to get data of only one document by it's ID in Flutter with Cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

That's how I do this, but that does not seem to be correct syntax.

```
static Future<void> sendPostInFirebase(
      String postID, String postContent, MyProfileData userProfile) async {

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('thread').document(postID).setData({
      'postID': postID,
      'userName': userProfile.myName,
      'userThumbnail': userProfile.myThumbnail,
      'postTimeStamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'postContent': postContent,
      'postLikeCount': 0,
      'postCommentCount': 0,
    });
```

And probably there is the same problem with cloud_firestore:

```
static Future<void> updatePostLikeCount(DocumentSnapshot postData,
      bool isLikePost, MyProfileData myProfileData) async {
    postData.reference.updateData(
        {'postLikeCount': FieldValue.increment(isLikePost ? -1 : 1)});
  }
```

I was not able to find any detailed documentation or  up-to-date answers, so...

Please help me if you can <3

Comment: "that does not seem to be correct syntax" Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
 
`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('thread').document(postID).setData({ `



**document(postID)** is highlighted as an error: The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an outdated SDK. Because Firestore documentation, especially for flutter is one of the best docs out there.

To do what you want, as per the latest SDK, change your code to this:

```
postData.update({'postLikeCount': FieldValue.increment(isLikePost ? -1 : 1)});
```

That's all. Because your document Id is stored inside the DocumentReference object `postData`.

Also, in your `set` logic, use `.set` instead of `.setData`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the second part of the question, but I still can't figure out why **document(postID)** doesn't work. I updated the Flutter SDK and Android Tools SDK, checked the ability to update plugins, but nothing has changed.

Comment: It's `doc(postID)`.

Comment: WOW, it is so simple. Thanks, now it works.